# Include Geocoder from OSM in Leaflet Map

Tags: leaflet, openstreetmap, geocoding

I need to embed a `Geocoder` from `OSM` into a `Leaflet` map.
When I include the `Geocoder` all my Icons disappear. Why?
I have shorten the data for this example.
Here is my code.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>

   <head>
     <title>Supermärkte</title>
     <meta charset="utf-8" />

     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ==" crossorigin="" />

     <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.6.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-gZwIG9x3wUXg2hdXF6+rVkLF/0Vi9U8D2Ntg4Ga5I5BZpVkVxlJWbSQtXPSiUTtC0TjtGOmxa1AJPuV0CPthew==" crossorigin=""></script>

   </head>
   <body>
     <div id="map" style="width: 700px; height: 640px"></div>   
    <script
        src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js">
    </script>
    <script
        src="http://k4r573n.github.io/leaflet-control-osm-geocoder/Control.OSMGeo\coder.js">
    </script>
     <script>



       var jsonDataObject = [
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 50.9415805,
               "lng" : 6.936476799999999
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 50.94297837989273,
                  "lng" : 6.937895379892722
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 50.94027872010729,
                  "lng" : 6.935195720107278
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
         "id" : "26b350c23b5506e8d68acd7c0ad499d5e4b0e450",
         "name" : "REWE",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 3496,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/104926697198871917978\"\u003eJulien Bourzac\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAA-NVIOFRx6fof0wuFfXtAXLkuyFTeJo9j0675ILg0dPjXcdYYg8hiEDUvBQ8_tOizgI2nvvqrsbQPQSKwMcz_3bq8XExh9SUrlNSDQVWBxNiTceW-wkTpBbTlA-F0kOSbEhCdLRQo_NJOG4rIi_1g0EhZGhQAMTYXdhcEUaMw_5kmEzKaYivYdA",
               "width" : 4656
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJc1qakgUlv0cR54gK8OOiB44",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "WWRP+JH Köln",
            "global_code" : "9F28WWRP+JH"
         },
         "rating" : 4.1,
         "reference" : "ChIJc1qakgUlv0cR54gK8OOiB44",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "supermarket",
            "grocery_or_supermarket",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "store",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 302,
         "vicinity" : "Venloer Str. 23, Köln"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 50.9074928,
               "lng" : 6.9710391
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 50.90880377989272,
                  "lng" : 6.972074279892723
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 50.90610412010728,
                  "lng" : 6.969374620107279
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
         "id" : "b9d2263aeaf8bcb1936cd7cf0878b755bef491ab",
         "name" : "REWE",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 4032,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/103420078876481741021\"\u003eA Google User\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAA2u7pcQ_viONEKFgkClDIWjCbUTLz41Fbz2gKGYvKzzAszByg-sKeOGb9GEJ63GVTpwIghlaiXzscNC_xKLLj38TxjONxxfqrjSNY_qnHuRIy5nhfdwta-RA2WxSmMf-LEhDkhnjirFsQxnRapGkTX2gpGhS0aIHc2_yFqbE60awRH-UY_u7PUA",
               "width" : 3024
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJt_ysaxYkv0cRK4u8qaQGxV0",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "WX4C+XC Köln",
            "global_code" : "9F28WX4C+XC"
         },
         "rating" : 4,
         "reference" : "ChIJt_ysaxYkv0cRK4u8qaQGxV0",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "supermarket",
            "grocery_or_supermarket",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "store",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 246,
         "vicinity" : "Goltsteinstraße 91, Köln"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 50.9514487,
               "lng" : 6.9568774
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 50.95279392989272,
                  "lng" : 6.958323279892721
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 50.95009427010728,
                  "lng" : 6.955623620107278
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
         "id" : "c372aaea8d0fb213eae385d15aa9c82f0bb7a06e",
         "name" : "REWE",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 4032,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/107643037961683176496\"\u003eMirko Bettels\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAJ_cfbjlUfTP24FZqnjO_JxsdHEam5Fjb4DoCchxc6pG3WW4uLGKuWZ470DK6KTYNZa6uaH522t0G-qTtItPyVskVUQxFad16Gl2mLCCy3QRECUKb-hl64PLCWL2pJCtQEhALGfBzMcTSG5RR8Zff_WwPGhSHs76RcQf5FQ4tgpKHBaZsErxTJw",
               "width" : 3024
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJcU4qf6Ilv0cRlyr5YInwb7s",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "XX24+HQ Köln",
            "global_code" : "9F28XX24+HQ"
         },
         "rating" : 4,
         "reference" : "ChIJcU4qf6Ilv0cRlyr5YInwb7s",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "supermarket",
            "grocery_or_supermarket",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "store",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 435,
         "vicinity" : "Neusser Str. 5-7, Köln"
      },
      {
         "geometry" : {
            "location" : {
               "lat" : 50.88138610000001,
               "lng" : 7.0776374
            },
            "viewport" : {
               "northeast" : {
                  "lat" : 50.88274812989273,
                  "lng" : 7.079345829892722
               },
               "southwest" : {
                  "lat" : 50.88004847010728,
                  "lng" : 7.076646170107278
               }
            }
         },
         "icon" : "https://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/place_api/icons/shopping-71.png",
         "id" : "8d469e0a727c46688231277811153d551a5b0a48",
         "name" : "Hit Markt",
         "opening_hours" : {
            "open_now" : true
         },
         "photos" : [
            {
               "height" : 1040,
               "html_attributions" : [
                  "\u003ca href=\"https://maps.google.com/maps/contrib/102427888486660810853\"\u003eHeike Boedeker\u003c/a\u003e"
               ],
               "photo_reference" : "CmRaAAAAX_l9ZgnhIP5bWdyOW6BbOwjvjAg1aS4H0P-PSC2bxjBIqto7bIBPoJAA_NsIZxMW7_nDhKHUsU2RTrcjRTKelA_BNcDjh9dNar0Esa7SmiKZzCMIo60z8LNjFpGa-kl_EhDLqHkUTTvBkHdvRqqs2DA_GhRZDtmyrVJ-io_KID6CIqCnKVBtHA",
               "width" : 1822
            }
         ],
         "place_id" : "ChIJEe-yK1Mnv0cRu7pdM3MAxG0",
         "plus_code" : {
            "compound_code" : "V3JH+H3 Köln",
            "global_code" : "9F29V3JH+H3"
         },
         "rating" : 3.9,
         "reference" : "ChIJEe-yK1Mnv0cRu7pdM3MAxG0",
         "scope" : "GOOGLE",
         "types" : [
            "supermarket",
            "grocery_or_supermarket",
            "food",
            "point_of_interest",
            "store",
            "establishment"
         ],
         "user_ratings_total" : 581,
         "vicinity" : "Marienburger Str. 1, Köln"
      }
     ];

       var map = L.map('map').setView([50.922082, 6.944733], 12);
       L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
         attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
       }).addTo(map);

       //var osmGeocoder = new L.Control.OSMGeocoder();


       var markerIcons = {
         "REWE": L.icon({
           iconUrl: 'rewe.png',
           iconSize: [55, 45],
           iconAnchor: [22, 94],
           popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "REWE Rahmati": L.icon({
           iconUrl: 'rewe.png',
           iconSize: [55, 45],
           iconAnchor: [22, 94],
           popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "REWE Center": L.icon({
           iconUrl: 'rewe.png',
           iconSize: [55, 45],
           iconAnchor: [22, 94],
           popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "REWE Richrath": L.icon({
           iconUrl: 'rewe.png',
           iconSize: [55, 45],
           iconAnchor: [22, 94],
           popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "REWE Markt GmbH": L.icon({
           iconUrl: 'rewe.png',
           iconSize: [55, 45],
           iconAnchor: [22, 94],
           popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "REWE To Go": L.icon({
           iconUrl: 'rewe.png',
           iconSize: [55, 45],
           iconAnchor: [22, 94],
           popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "REWE To Go bei Aral": L.icon({
           iconUrl: 'rewe.png',
           iconSize: [55, 45],
           iconAnchor: [22, 94],
           popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "REWE Holger Rohe oHG": L.icon({
           iconUrl: 'rewe.png',
           iconSize: [55, 45],
           iconAnchor: [22, 94],
           popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Netto Filiale": L.icon({
           iconUrl: 'netto.png',
           iconSize: [45, 35],
           iconAnchor: [22, 94],
           popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
          "Netto Marken-Discount City": L.icon({
           iconUrl: 'netto.png',
           iconSize: [45, 35],
           iconAnchor: [22, 94],
           popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
          "Netto City Filiale": L.icon({
           iconUrl: 'netto.png',
           iconSize: [45, 35],
           iconAnchor: [22, 94],
           popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "ALDI SÜD": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'aldi.png',
         iconSize: [32, 42],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
          "Lidl": L.icon({
           iconUrl: 'lidl.png',
           iconSize: [35, 35],
           iconAnchor: [22, 94],
           popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "NORMA": L.icon({
           iconUrl: 'norma.png',
           iconSize: [35, 20],
           iconAnchor: [22, 94],
           popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "NORMA Filiale": L.icon({
           iconUrl: 'norma.jpg',
           iconSize: [35, 20],
           iconAnchor: [22, 94],
           popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Kaufland": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'kaufland.png',
         iconSize: [35, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Kaufland Köln-Niehl": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'kaufland.png',
         iconSize: [35, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Kaufland Köln-Ehrenfeld": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'kaufland.png',
         iconSize: [35, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Kaufland Köln-Kalk": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'kaufland.png',
         iconSize: [35, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Kaufland Köln-Merheim": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'kaufland.png',
         iconSize: [35, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Kaufland Köln-Mülheim": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'kaufland.png',
         iconSize: [35, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "dm-drogerie markt": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'dm.png',
         iconSize: [40, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Wodarz Getränkemarkt": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Edeka Center Engels Marsdorf GmbH": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Edeka Engels": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Peters": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Gans": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Edeka": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Edeka Daub e.K": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Edeka Center Engels Widdersdorf": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Edeka Romano": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Wodarz": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Klausemann": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Weiden": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Hein": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Feldmann-Höner": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Edeka - Die Kippings": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Edeka Blomeier": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Edeka Aktiv Markt Hetzenegger": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA STEFFENS": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Jung": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Eedeka Markt Hein": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Fischmarkt Zickuhr": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Stahl": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Klein": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Hetzenegger": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA-Markt Frischecenter J. Engels GbR": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Geurtz": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Wünsch": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Hetzenegger Getränkemarkt": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Edeka Klein Hessling": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Breuer": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Höner": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Schröder": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Zickuhr": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Köln-Merheim": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Edeka Jünger": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Edeka Klein-Heßling": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Mülln": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Edeka Bonus": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Breidohr-Frischecenter": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Blaschek": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Markt Dünnwald": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Edeka Daub KG": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Kausemann": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA - Die Kippings": L.icon({
        iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Edeka Markt Hein": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Frischmarkt Zickuhr": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "EDEKA Frischmarkt Zickuhr": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'edeka.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "PENNY": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'penny.jpg',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "HIT Handelsgruppe GmbH & Co. KG": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'hit.png',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Hit Markt": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'hit.png',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
         "Hit.": L.icon({
         iconUrl: 'hit.png',
         iconSize: [30, 30],
         iconAnchor: [22, 94],
         popupAnchor: [-3, -76],
         }),
       };

      //map.addControl(osmGeocoder);

       for (let i = 0; i < jsonDataObject.length; i++) {
         var lat = parseFloat(jsonDataObject[i].geometry.location.lat);
         var lng = parseFloat(jsonDataObject[i].geometry.location.lng);
         console.log(jsonDataObject[i].name)

         var marker = L.marker([lat, lng], {
           icon: markerIcons[jsonDataObject[i].name]
         });

         marker.bindPopup(jsonDataObject[i].name, {
           autoClose: false
         });
         map.addLayer(marker);
         marker.myJsonData = jsonDataObject[i];




       };

     </script>
   </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: Remove second Leaflet include (version 0.7).

Comment: @TomazicM I did remove the seconds Leaflet `<script
        src="http://cdn.leafletjs.com/leaflet-0.7/leaflet.js">
    </script>` and what shall I include?

Comment: Nothing, it should work now. If it doesn't, do you get any errors in debugger console?

Comment: By the way, link to Geocoder http://k4r573n.github.io/leaflet-control-osm-geocoder/Control.OSMGeo\coder.js does not exist.

Comment: The console shows me 2 errors `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)` and 
`index.html:15395 Uncaught TypeError: L.Control.OSMGeocoder is not a constructor
    at index.html:15395`

Comment: @TomazicM is there an alternative?

Comment: Yes, download plugin files and call them locally from where you have your html.

Comment: you mean the `geocoder` plugin? Where can I find the right one?

Comment: On Leaflet pages there is a link to all the Leaflet plugins: https://leafletjs.com/plugins.html. Among them you can find link for Leaflet Control OSM Geocoder plugin: https://github.com/k4r573n/leaflet-control-osm-geocoder. From there you can download necessary ZIP files at https://github.com/k4r573n/leaflet-control-osm-geocoder/archive/master.zip